# My computer does not want to start-up

Tags: startup, login-screen

I copied photos onto my notebook hard drive and got a warning of limited hard drive space...I continued to copy photos onto my hard dirve. I got a message that the space limit was reached an no more photos could be copied onto the hard drive.

I restarted my notebook and the initial Ubuntu page could not load due to lack of memory. I tried to start-up in safe mode, buit to no avail. I guess that will mean that I uninstall Ubuntu completely and reinstall it again.

I have all important stuff backed up in case I need to unistall Ubuntu. My screen is black at the moment with my computer name prompting for the password. When I type in the password I get a message" the configuration defaults for GNOME Power Manager have not been installed correctly. See administrator."

What can I do and how do I do it?

Comment: Hopefully next time you'll remember not to fill up all the space on your hard drive ;-) (any OS needs a little bit of free disk space to work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try a terminal Ctrl+alt+F1
- Boot with live CD

And delete files

Comment: I dont have a live CD...I downloaded Ubuntu online.

Comment: I also did not mention that I am running windows as well.

Comment: There are ext-Drivers for windows, but I never tried them.
Did you install Ubuntu with the wubi installer?

Comment: I am not sure...I downloaded from 10.4 from Ubuntu website and installed it...is there a way to uninstall Ubuntu without touching windows?...I'll reinstall ubuntu again as soon as I cleared some space off my notebook.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-F1 as suggested should work.

Comment: The suggestion should work. If you installed it inside windows you can remove it as any other program. If you have an ISO of ubuntu you can use something like http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ to create live usb. Checkout https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows

Comment: I tried Crtl-Alt-F1...put my laptop login and password...message now is: hylton@hylton:~$   ....where to from here.

Comment: type<br>
sudo apt-get autoclean<br>
<your password><br>
Reboot and it should work

Comment: type "sudo apt-get autoclean" (without ") then your password Reboot and it should work